# How can I get rid of CodeMirror div ? And why do I have it?

Tags: php, google-chrome

While I was working on PHP pages, suddenly I got this part on the page without any action from me.
It appears only on Chrome.
How can I get rid of it?
Why did I get it?

[image]

Comment: looks like it's inserted with your code editor. Open your file with notepad and see if it actually has the div.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that because that I have a Chrome extension called **JSON Viewer
0.18.1**
Deactivating the extension solved the problem!